# Redux toolkit actionCreator warn: Invalid number of arguments, expected 0

Tags: redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

it's action:

```
export const someAction = createAction('SOME_ACTION')
```

Is there a way to fix it?

> Invalid number of arguments, expected 0

```
dispatch(someAction({key: 'val'}))
```

Okay, I found how, you just need to add function prepare by second argument like this

```
export const someAction = createAction('SOME_ACTION', prepare)
```

well, after this the next warn in saga

> Unresolved variable type someAction.type

```
function* watch() {
  yield takeLatest(someAction.type, getOneClientWork);
}
```

OMG!

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? The `const someAction = createAction('SOME_ACTION')` part is entirely valid, and the error message looks like it's a TypeScript error.

Comment: no typescript :(

Comment: Are you using a JetBrains IDE to write this, like WebStorm, PhpStorm, or Intellij? Googling that error suggests it's a common message reported by those IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

As for your second problem: Try

```js
function* watch() {
  yield takeLatest(someAction, getOneClientWork);
}
```

But in general, those are TypeScript warnings that come from your IDE applying TypeScript to pure, untyped JavaScript code - in the hopes of giving you better autocompletion and hints. Unfortunatley, stuff like that goes wrong a lot of times.

So if you were writing TypeScript, you'd write

```
export const someAction = createAction<PayloadType>('SOME_ACTION')
```

and if you don't do that, it goes back to the default behaviour:

```
export const someAction = createAction('SOME_ACTION')
// defaults to
export const someAction = createAction<void>('SOME_ACTION')
```

and would mean "this takes no payload".

Now your IDE blindly applies TypeScript there, uses the default `void` and you end up with warnings that don't really concern you.